# How to check successful compilation in PDFLaTeX?

Tags: compiling, git, hooks

I want to develop a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) for my LaTeX Git repository.
I need the hook to suppress the commit in case the compilation finishes unsuccessfully (missing packages OR missing source files OR missing images OR no PDF generated -anything else I forgot?).

Is there a standard way of checking the compilation status (success/failed) I could use for my hook?

I use my own `build.sh` script where I generate document history from Git tags, run a few `pdflatex` commands, and clean the intermediate files. I run it under Win10, MikTeX, but want to make the hook universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, just a hint... but...

You can check the exit status of `pdflatex`. If it's different from 0, something has gone wrong. As a reference, this is my Python3 snippet that compiles a string containing a full LaTeX source:

```python
import os
import sys
def latex_string(bigstr, outname="out"): 
    """ Compile with pdflatex the string passed as argument. 
        Notice that the output files are overwritten, no questions.
    """
    f = open(outname+".tex", mode="w") 
    print(bigstr, file=f)
    f.close()
    ecode=os.system("pdflatex %s >/dev/null </dev/null" % outname) 
    if ecode==0:
        os.system("rm -f {0}.aux {0}.log {0}.out".format(outname))
        pass
    else:
        print("pdflatex error code: %d" % ecode, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

In `bash`, you can check the variable `$?` right after calling `pdflatex`.

Comment: That's great, but how to handle the question-tag marked questions pdfLaTeX asks in case some resource is not available? There are the interaction modes, but which is the best to use in my scenario?

Comment: @MaciekS --- sorry, I really never wrote a git hook; it was just an hint...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I saw so many posts in this topic suggesting I have to check the log and pdf file consistency, that I didn't realize pdfLaTeX simply returns the code.

Answer (score 1):

As the (pdf)LaTeX compilers simply return the error code, the task is quite simple.

I decided to use the `latexmk` in order to properly handle the number of runs.

Finally my `pre-commit` hook looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S" -logfilewarninglist -silent document
exec git update-server-info
```

If there is an error in my LaTeX code, so that no output can be generated, the Git commit is interrupted.